# mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource , array given {Laravel}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, highcharts

`$result=DB::table('Table_26') ->select('id','data','((unix_timestamp(time) * 1000) as datetime)
->order_by('datetime')
->get();`

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result['sql'])) {
$rows[] = $r; }
print json_encode($rows);
```

---

a get problem of

> mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

---

i want to get like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?callback=a)

---

i need this to working with [highstock](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/)

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look back through the Laravel documentation. `mysql_*` functions in PHP are depreciated and you shouldn't need to go anywhere near them whilst using Laravel.

Comment: i didn't get what you mean bro , can you explain more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$result=DB::table('Table_26') ->select('id','data','((unix_timestamp(time) * 1000) as datetime)->order_by('datetime')->get()->toArray();`
 - then:

```
while($r = $result['sql']) {
```

Comment: ahh ok, no problem ;)